# tag partial tree vs full trunk in svn

Tags: svn, version-control, tags

We have a repository with the following structure:

```
repos
  trunk
    module1
    module2
    ...
  tags
  branches
```

We usually release individual modules to the customer and sometimes the whole application.

Now we are going to deliver module1 and I'm trying to decide between these two options:

- a) tag module1 (i.e. copy trunk/module1 to tags/module1_v1.00)
- b) tag the full trunk (i.e copy trunk to tags/v1.00)

Is there any convention that all tags should include the full trunk? 
Is there any good reason to do one thing or the other?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no extra cost one way or the other, is there something you don't like about tagging the whole trunk?

Comment: It's not a matter of cost. If I'm releasing module1, I don't care about the state in which module2 may be. Perhaps module2 is in the middle of some work and shouldn't be tagged right now. Also I want to make it clear that I'm releasing module1, and not any other module.

Answer (score 5):

if there are inter-dependencies then you should tag all, otherwise tagging just one is fine.  Either way, you want to be consistent.

If you tag a module, the path should be:

```
/tags/rel_1.0/module1
```

not

```
/tags/module1_v1.0
```

Of course you can make it whatever you want, but it's best to follow SVN recommendations.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html

Comment: I can't find the svn recommendation for this particular issue. 
If I follow your advice, then when creating v1.00 of module2 maybe two weeks later, it will live in the same rel_1.0 directory... and I can't tell whether it is v1.00 of the whole project or v1.00 of module1 and then v1.00 of module2

Comment: if your "modules" are that disjointed then you should not keep them all within one trunk and instead each should have it's own set of tags/branches/trunk directories.

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like

```
trunk
  module1
  module2
tags
  fullProject
  components
    module1
    module2
```

That way you can label your module releases independently of your full project releases.  For example `tags/components/module1/20091217`.