# Tag jenkins from trunk instead of src

Tags: svn, hudson, jenkins

We create jenkins job using path to the src dir in the the respository of the app we wan't to integrate continuously. (For example : https://svn.server.tld/trunk/src/app

But when we want to tag from a build, the entire path is proposed to be tagged, we wan't to have the tag created from https://svn.server.tld/trunk/.

We can change the URL and use Included Regions (to ignore commit on other part of the repository), but when jenkins checkout, it will check out the entire repos... not very optimized.

I saw that svn is able to check out only one dir (trunk for instance) :
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html
But how to tell jenkins to make such a thing...

Edit : we want to tag the entire trunk (even if there are other way of thinking : [tag partial tree vs full trunk in svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923922/tag-partial-tree-vs-full-trunk-in-svn) ) because there are some specs (that we want to tagged at the same time than sources are) at other level on our repository.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins gives you the [Subversion revision number](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) as an environment variable, and you know the URL of the trunk.

Download the [post-build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task). Then, create a post-build task to do an `svn cp` to tag the release.

By the way, there's really no reason to tag each and every build in Subversion. Jenkins tracks the repository revision number, so you can always branch from that, or create a production release from that.

Comment: We don't want to automate tagging, we only want to use the "Tag this build" button on the left menu of a build page.

Comment: You can try the [Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin). That allows you to do an action when you want. The only issue is that the `$SVN_REVISION` environment variable has no value when this plugin runs, and you can't pull it out with "svn info". However, in `$WORKSPACE/../builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/revision.txt` (or something like that) is the Subversion repository revision of that build.

Comment: Agree with @David W., the Release Plugin might be what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [SVN tagging plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin)

Comment: As already said, we don't want to automate tagging, we want to keep this a manual because it's for creating pre-release/release tags.

Comment: There is also a Tag This Build plugin